# How to add navigable url in react bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am fetching data from database to react-bootstrap table in JSON format. One field is url and displayed as string. How can I change it to link and redirect to the respective site? 
For instance, if json.url = "www.google.com", cell should display json.url and onClick it should redirect to google site.

Comment: Please share a code sample of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td>
    <a href={json.url}>{json.url}</a>
</td>
```

Comment: @usergs You could do <a href={json.url} target="_blank">{json.url}</a>